# How to get Laravel Login query? I can't pass the login page

Tags: laravel

I wanna get the Login query because I have some problem on login page.

Actually there's no error when I used Laravel Migrations (the login system worked at all), after a day, I tried again but using SQL Manually and got a problem.

I wanna know what does Laravel do with sql query, seems laravel do query on wrong fields.

I've tried to use DD($request->all()); and the output like this

[Die Dump output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNU8G.png)

^ If you notice at the password, it doesn't encrypted.
But in my database, it's encrypted

[password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdKWD.png)

And this happen if i didn't use DD

[Login credentials do not match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4QoK.png)

function on LoginController.php for login using username or email, i found this code [from this tutorial](https://medium.com/innohub/laravel-5-6-customizing-default-auth-part-2-login-with-username-or-email-e66a70217178)

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(
        $request,
        [
            'identity' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ],
        [
            'identity.required' => 'Username or email is required',
            'password.required' => 'Password is required',
        ]
    );
    // dd($request->all());
}
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @throws ValidationException
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->flash('login_error', trans('auth.failed'));
    throw ValidationException::withMessages(
        [
            'error' => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Laravel Auth default using `email`, not `username`, please check it first.

Comment: I've updated the post, I forgot to add my code.

Comment: I use a function from this tutorial: https://medium.com/innohub/laravel-5-6-customizing-default-auth-part-2-login-with-username-or-email-e66a70217178

For login using "username or email"

Comment: can you share the view part of your code

Comment: I think you missing overwrite `credentials` function to verify `username` or `email`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something mentioned here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/authenticate-on-custom-fields-laravel-53

basically laravel is looking for a specific field name while using default auth, but since yours differ from that you have to change them manually

Comment: I updated my post, 
I use a function from this tutorial: https://medium.com/innohub/laravel-5-6-customizing-default-auth-part-2-login-with-username-or-email-e66a70217178

 For login using "username or email"

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use laravel's default authenticatication using this command
    php artisan make:auth

Comment: I already used default laravel authentication using php artisan make:auth, but I modifed something like user multiauth + approval + email verification + using custom fields